# Drupal - log in a newly created user in PHP

Tags: php, drupal, ubercart

I have Ubercart installed. I'd like to create a Conditional Action after an anonymous user finishes checking out. The system currently creates a user automatically, but it does not log them in - I want this conditional action to log them in.

The conditional action allows me to write custom PHP to perform whatever I want - and what I want to do is log in the user. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

No need to write your own conditional action. Visit your site at:

`http://yoursite.com/admin/store/settings/checkout/edit/basic`

there's a checkbox towards the bottom of the page that if enabled will allow you to automatically check-in users that are created automatically by the system at checkout.

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

It depends what variables you got. In Drupal, the global `$user` is the user object of the logged in user so you can do something like this:

```
global $user; // if user isn't logged in, $user is the anonymous user.
$user = user_load($uid); // $user is now the user you loaded.
```

You have to take care when doing stuff like this, so you don't accidentally log in users with the wrong user, like a user with admin privileges. In the above example, `$uid` is the id of the user you want to get.